# Adding a view from SQL Server to MS Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, view

For a school exercise I had to make a view in MS SQL Server and use it for a report in MS Access.

I've made the view in SQL SERVER, but how can I import it into MS Access so that I can use it? 
The SQLServer DB is linked with MS Access.

I have made a form for the previous exercise, now I want to make a Report that gives the data from the view I made. I tried using our reader and google, but they are not giving the answer I need. It seems something very simple I am missing out. Just don't get how to update the DB in Access or something, when I make something in SQL Server, it doesn't get added to Access automatically even though I linked them..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [edit] your post.

Comment: You can import or link tables from SQL Server into Access but you cannot do the same with views. You could copy the SQL from your SQL Server view and edit it to create an Access query.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot! Explains why I couldn't find it.

Comment: You CAN link to a view in Access, exactly the same way as you do with a table, But you have to have at least select permission on the SQL server to be able to see it.

Comment: Really? But how can I set select permissions?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql -- but it would be strange if you can see the tables but not views. From Access' point of view, a linked view is pretty much the same as a linked table. Except you have to set the PK manually when linking (if you want to edit the data).

Comment: Basics about linking: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-data-in-an-SQL-Server-database-a5a3b4eb-57b9-45a0-b732-77bc6089b84e